# Complex Derivative of Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am working on this question and its "simplicity" is sort of throwing me off.

"Assume that the series $\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n(z − z_0)^n$ converges in $A_{r,R} (z_0)$ with $0 \leq r < R$.
Define the function
\begin{equation}
f(z) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} a_n(z − z_0)^n.
\end{equation}
Show that $f(z)$ is differentiable for $z \in A_{r,R} (z_0)$ and calculate the differential."

Do I need to split the Laurent series into both its regular and singular parts as they both converge?

Comment: Take into account that you are avoiding the only singularity, say $z_0$, with this domain. So, your strategy would works.

Comment: You don't *need* to split the Laurent series, but doing that will probably simplify the proof. (It depends on what you already know about Laurent series, and about holomorphic functions in general. If you know enough, splitting doesn't simplify.)

Comment: This is my first course in complex function theory! But if you could expand a bit that would be helpful :)